# How to display custom agenda-view on Emacs startup?

Tags: emacs, startup, org-mode

I have

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook 'org-agenda)
```

in my init file. This displays the agenda *dispatcher*. How can I

1. automatically display a custom view (shortcut "w")
2. make sure the agenda view is the only window and there is no *scratch* buffer in a second window?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook (lambda () (org-agenda nil "w")))
```

@robust: you can get more information through the help page for using `org-agenda` non-interactively (`C-h f org-agenda`); note that the original `(interactive)` in the `lambda` was unneeded, so I edited it out.  The first optional argument is the prefix argument so pass it a placeholder, but the second (`ORG-KEYS`) is the one you want to set to your key of interest (`"w"`).  You wrap the call to `org-agenda` in a `lambda`, which is self-quoting.

Comment: Thanks, this works great! Now, how can I make sure to only display the agenda window, i.e. automatically press "o"?
Also, if you don't mind, can you explain how the `(lambda () (interactive) (org-agenda t "w"))` part works?

Comment: Explanation of the `lambda` is now in the answer.  Re: "display only agenda window": unless you have other initializations that split windows, that should be the default.  It only shows up with one, unsplit window on my setup, at any rate.

Comment: I could not find anything in my init file that creates the second window. Maybe org-agenda automatically creates a second window? Anyways, I just added `(add-hook 'after-init-hook (lambda () (delete-other-windows)) t)` and this solves the problem.

Comment: Just found a nice alternative to the `delete-other-windows` approach, which is simply setting `(setq org-agenda-window-setup 'current-window)`.